# Raspbian crashes when connecting to AP

Tags: raspbian, wireless

Following Raspberry Pi's own tutorial for setting up an access point (https://github.com/raspberrypi/documentation/blob/master/configuration/wireless/access-point.md) from a clean Raspbian Buster image with updated and upgraded packages, Raspbian crashes consistently when connecting to the access point from another computer. The access point is from a USB dongle on the Pi.

I'm obviously unable to share what's logged to the screen since the Pi becomes completely unresponsive and the only way to recover it is to pull the power and then plug it back in.

I was able to narrow down the problem by running through the same tutorial on the `2018-11-13-raspbian-stretch-lite` archived Raspbian image. I followed the exact same steps with the same hardware (but without upgrading the packages!) and everything worked fine as before.

It seems the the problem is due to some updated package in the past few months, but I can't seem to narrow down exactly which one.

Has anyone else experienced something similar?

Comment: `'m obviously unable to share what's logged to the screen` why? there's log files, there's cameras, there's pen and paper :D

Comment: Sorry for this bad quality, but this is the best I could do: https://youtu.be/ES7TwySB4i8

The crash isn't saved to any of the system logs.

Comment: so that video shows when another computer connects to the pi? It looked like a boot sequence of the pi - oh, wait, second viewing, i see that it isn't

Comment: Correct. The name of the access point is MissionMule. As soon as I try to connect  (time 0:01 in the video) from another computer, there's sort of kernel/memory dump.

Comment: can you post the details of the USB dongle and which model pi is it

Comment: I notice you have kernel 4.19.57 - I think the current is 4.19.58 - so perhaps the other thing to try is another update :p

Comment: I'm using a RTL8192CU chipset. The problem persists with another dongle with another RTL8xxxu chipset, I can't find which one exactly.

This happened with a clean download of the latest Raspbian lite image. I updated and upgraded the packages before running through the tutorial so everything should have been up to date as much as possible.

Comment: maybe the update from .57 to .58 is very recent, but yeah, my pi's are all at .58 - I'm surprised that none of that output is in any log file in /var/log though

Comment: you still haven't said which Pi you are using - also, that tutorial shows how to use onboard wifi for access point, and states *`it is possible that some USB dongles may need slight changes to their settings. If you are having trouble with a USB wireless dongle, please check the forums`* also there's two different setups, NAT and BRIDGE - which one are you doing?

Comment: I'm using a 3B+.

I'm doing just the NAT part of the tutorial.

Comment: have you tried using the onboard wifi instead? did you need to make any changes for using the USB wifi?

Comment: I tried to implement hostapd using the built-in WiFi and two different T-Link wifi adapters (TL-WN722N and TL-WN422G, with Atheros AR9271 and ZyDAS ZD1211B chips). The three of them worked for a while, but eventually crashed. It tried every solution found in Internet. I gave up and went back to using a separate wifi router.

Answer (score 0):

I have had this same issue occur with the latest Lite versions of Buster, Stretch, and Jessie, on Pi 3 B+ with Edimax Dongles and onboard wifi, and Pi 2 B+ with Edimax Dongles. Something is wrong with the kernel relating to wireless drivers, but not sure how to capture the kernel panic to dig through it. I dug out an old copy of Jessie and avoided updates like the plague. There was some discussion about wireless driver issues on the Raspberry Pi forum (I think from back in March..?) but there wasn't a lot of resolution.

**Update** from a comment:
Downgrading to 2018-11-13-raspbian-stretch-lite from https://downloads.raspberrypi.org/raspbian_lite/images/ worked for me when I don't upgrade the packages. This obviously doesn't actually fix the problem, but rolls back to a working state. It'd be great to get to the root cause of this to fix it in the newer versions of Raspbian.

Comment: And what exactly do you suggest to solve the problem? Downgrade to an old copy of Jessie? From where and how? Its old-old stable.

Comment: Downgrading to 2018-11-13-raspbian-stretch-lite from https://downloads.raspberrypi.org/raspbian_lite/images/ worked for me when I don't upgrade the packages. This obviously doesn't actually fix the problem, but rolls back to a working state. It'd be great to get to the root cause of this to fix it in the newer versions of Raspbian.